# PhoneGap2.1 iOS6 crash on resume (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: iphone, cordova, ios6

The phenomenon:

happens only on ios6 not happening on ios5

App is suspended (click on power btn on top) and immediately (~1-2 sec) resumed --> no issue

App is suspended and resume after awhile  (1-2 min) --> app crashed

it seems totally unrelated to app functionality as it happens on every screen including the one that just show photo + login with facebook btn (before doing login with FB)

I would appreciate any help here

Warnings before app crash

```
Oct 21 19:40:52 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone backboardd[52] <Warning>: CoreAnimation: updates deferred for too long
Oct 21 19:40:52 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone backboardd[52] <Warning>: CoreAnimation: timed out fence 25567
Oct 21 19:40:52 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone SpringBoard[69] <Warning>: CoreAnimation: failed to receive fence reply: 10004003
```

Crash report

```
Oct 21 19:40:52 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process socialPlace[4544]
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:net.socialplace.ios[0x9fa5][4544]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:net.socialplace.ios[0x9fa5]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone backboardd[52] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:net.socialplace.ios[0x9fa5]' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Not saving crash log because we have reached the limit for logs to store on disk.  Sync or otherwise clear logs from /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter to save new logs.
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Could not save crash report to disk!
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Incident Identifier: FB82D672-4DD9-4316-96B5-95591B4EA7C8
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: CrashReporter Key:   571a819d6942642be43b1132967c9fcdb607ff24
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Process:         socialPlace [4544]
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/0F954FA6-B820-46A5-9053-DA09D9A17A39/socialPlace.app/socialPlace
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Identifier:      socialPlace
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Version:         ??? (???)
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Parent Process:  launchd [1]
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:  
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Date/Time:       2012-10-21 19:40:52.242 +0200
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: OS Version:      iOS 6.0 (10A403)
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Report Version:  104
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:  
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000009
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Crashed Thread:  2
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:  
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 0:
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x31a310fc 0x31a20000 + 69884
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bb0124 0x39baf000 + 4388
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 2   WebCore                        0x35319a1c 0x3530d000 + 51740
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 3   WebCore                        0x3531a922 0x3530d000 + 55586
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 4   UIKit                          0x3736aa04 0x370fb000 + 2554372
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 5   socialPlace                    0x00114a68 0xde000 + 223848
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 6   socialPlace                    0x00114a14 0xde000 + 223764
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 7   Foundation                     0x338f08e8 0x3383f000 + 727272
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 8   CoreFoundation                 0x35e02680 0x35d6b000 + 620160
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 9   CoreFoundation                 0x35e01ee4 0x35d6b000 + 618212
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 10  CoreFoundation                 0x35e00cb2 0x35d6b000 + 613554
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 11  CoreFoundation                 0x35d73eb8 0x35d6b000 + 36536
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 12  CoreFoundation                 0x35d73d44 0x35d6b000 + 36164
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 13  GraphicsServices               0x362b02e6 0x362ab000 + 21222
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 14  UIKit                          0x371522fc 0x370fb000 + 357116
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 15  socialPlace                    0x000e06b2 0xde000 + 9906
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 16  socialPlace                    0x000e0664 0xde000 + 9828
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:  
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 1:
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x31a21648 0x31a20000 + 5704
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 1   libdispatch.dylib              0x34b24974 0x34b1c000 + 35188
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 2   libdispatch.dylib              0x34b24654 0x34b1c000 + 34388
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:  
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 2 Crashed:
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 0   WebCore                        0x353ab2c2 0x3530d000 + 647874
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 1   WebCore                        0x353ab20a 0x3530d000 + 647690
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 2   CoreFoundation                 0x35e025dc 0x35d6b000 + 619996
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 3   CoreFoundation                 0x35e0228c 0x35d6b000 + 619148
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 4   CoreFoundation                 0x35e00efc 0x35d6b000 + 614140
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 5   CoreFoundation                 0x35d73eb8 0x35d6b000 + 36536
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 6   CoreFoundation                 0x35d73d44 0x35d6b000 + 36164
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 7   WebCore                        0x35317a70 0x3530d000 + 43632
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 8   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bc030e 0x39baf000 + 70414
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 9   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bc01d4 0x39baf000 + 70100
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:  
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 3:
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x31a20eb4 0x31a20000 + 3764
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x31a21048 0x31a20000 + 4168
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 2   CoreFoundation                 0x35e02040 0x35d6b000 + 618560
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 3   CoreFoundation                 0x35e00d9e 0x35d6b000 + 613790
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 4   CoreFoundation                 0x35d73eb8 0x35d6b000 + 36536
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 5   CoreFoundation                 0x35d73d44 0x35d6b000 + 36164
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 6   Foundation                     0x3386cbc8 0x3383f000 + 187336
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 7   Foundation                     0x338f0678 0x3383f000 + 726648
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 8   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bc030e 0x39baf000 + 70414
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 9   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bc01d4 0x39baf000 + 70100
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:  
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 4 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 4:
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x31a3108c 0x31a20000 + 69772
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bb8d2a 0x39baf000 + 40234
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bb8aa0 0x39baf000 + 39584
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 3   JavaScriptCore                 0x3a23cad0 0x3a1e1000 + 375504
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 4   JavaScriptCore                 0x3a34e55a 0x3a1e1000 + 1496410
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 5   JavaScriptCore                 0x3a360fb0 0x3a1e1000 + 1572784
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 6   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bc030e 0x39baf000 + 70414
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 7   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bc01d4 0x39baf000 + 70100
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:  
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 5 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 5:
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x31a3108c 0x31a20000 + 69772
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bb8d2a 0x39baf000 + 40234
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bc2f14 0x39baf000 + 81684
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 3   JavaScriptCore                 0x3a2e1f44 0x3a1e1000 + 1052484
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 4   JavaScriptCore                 0x3a2e1e84 0x3a1e1000 + 1052292
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 5   JavaScriptCore                 0x3a360fb0 0x3a1e1000 + 1572784
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 6   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bc030e 0x39baf000 + 70414
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 7   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bc01d4 0x39baf000 + 70100
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:  
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 6 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 6:
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x31a20eb4 0x31a20000 + 3764
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x31a21048 0x31a20000 + 4168
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 2   CoreFoundation                 0x35e02040 0x35d6b000 + 618560
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 3   CoreFoundation                 0x35e00d9e 0x35d6b000 + 613790
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 4   CoreFoundation                 0x35d73eb8 0x35d6b000 + 36536
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 5   CoreFoundation                 0x35d73d44 0x35d6b000 + 36164
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 6   WebCore                        0x353b2f9a 0x3530d000 + 679834
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 7   JavaScriptCore                 0x3a360fb0 0x3a1e1000 + 1572784
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 8   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bc030e 0x39baf000 + 70414
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 9   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bc01d4 0x39baf000 + 70100
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:  
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 7 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 7:
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x31a31594 0x31a20000 + 71060
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 1   CoreFoundation                 0x35e061f2 0x35d6b000 + 635378
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bc030e 0x39baf000 + 70414
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 3   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bc01d4 0x39baf000 + 70100
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:  
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 8:
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x31a20eb4 0x31a20000 + 3764
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x31a21048 0x31a20000 + 4168
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 2   CoreFoundation                 0x35e02040 0x35d6b000 + 618560
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 3   CoreFoundation                 0x35e00d9e 0x35d6b000 + 613790
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 4   CoreFoundation                 0x35d73eb8 0x35d6b000 + 36536
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 5   CoreFoundation                 0x35dd29b6 0x35d6b000 + 424374
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 6   CoreMotion                     0x33ea6ef2 0x33e75000 + 204530
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 7   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bc030e 0x39baf000 + 70414
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 8   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bc01d4 0x39baf000 + 70100
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:  
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 9:
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x31a31d98 0x31a20000 + 73112
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bb5cf6 0x39baf000 + 27894
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bb5a12 0x39baf000 + 27154
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 3   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bb58a0 0x39baf000 + 26784
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:  
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 10:
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x31a31d98 0x31a20000 + 73112
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bb5cf6 0x39baf000 + 27894
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bb5a12 0x39baf000 + 27154
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 3   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bb58a0 0x39baf000 + 26784
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:  
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 11:
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x31a31d98 0x31a20000 + 73112
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bb5cf6 0x39baf000 + 27894
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bb5a12 0x39baf000 + 27154
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 3   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bb58a0 0x39baf000 + 26784
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:  
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 12:
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x31a31d98 0x31a20000 + 73112
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bb5cf6 0x39baf000 + 27894
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bb5a12 0x39baf000 + 27154
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 3   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bb58a0 0x39baf000 + 26784
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:  
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 13:
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x31a31d98 0x31a20000 + 73112
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bb5cf6 0x39baf000 + 27894
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bb5a12 0x39baf000 + 27154
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 3   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39bb58a0 0x39baf000 + 26784
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:  
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Thread 2 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:     r0: 0x00000001    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x0516f1cc
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:     r4: 0x00254168    r5: 0x05da2464      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x0043b170
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:     r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x00091500     r10: 0x3b8cfb40     r11: 0x1d584628
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:     ip: 0x3b7c2bc4    sp: 0x0043b130      lr: 0x353ab2c1      pc: 0x353ab2c2
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:   cpsr: 0x60000030
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:  
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: Binary Images:
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>:    0xde000 -   0x15bfff +socialPlace armv7  <a6f06e87b6cf32f7b6302e6373dccb2e> /var/mobile/Applications/0F954FA6-B820-46A5-9053-DA09D9A17A39/socialPlace.app/socialPlace
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 0x2fe18000 - 0x2fe38fff  dyld armv7  <75594988728831d98e1f7c4c7b7ca29d> /usr/lib/dyld
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 0x31a20000 - 0x31a36fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <f167dacec44b3a86a8eee73400ff7a83> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 0x31a93000 - 0x31aa1fff  AssetsLibrary armv7  <f0d1ee22421532798858b19b2240d7df> /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 0x31ab1000 - 0x31ac4fff  DataDetectorsUI armv7  <072e054dc6d13fcca1ab6c241a9dc96a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 0x31ad6000 - 0x31aebfff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e79b59a3406f34d9b37f8085955115ce> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
Oct 21 19:40:53 Sharon-Mantins-iPhone ReportCrash[4562] <Error>: 0x31c9e000 - 0x31d63fff  CFNetwork armv7  <3e973794a4d13428bb974edcb2027139> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using web sockets? I had a similar problem and since I disabled websockets on the server I have not seen the problem

Here is a reference to the bug in sockets.io:
https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/pull/426

For some reason it did not work to implement this fix either, and upgrading to latest version of sockets.io did not resolve the issue.